# Why does adding INLINE slow down my program

Tags: haskell, inline

I was looking into making a `foldl` that worked on infinite lists, for situations where you could not obtain guarded recursion but where depending the first argument the second argument might not be used.

For example multiplication, where usually you need both arguments and guarded recursion does not work, but if the first argument is 0 you can short circuit.

So I wrote the following function:

```
foldlp :: (b -> a -> b) -> (b -> Bool) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldlp f p = go where
    go b [] = b
    go b (x : xs) 
        | p b = go (f b x) xs
        | otherwise = b
```

And tested it with my custom short circuiting multiplication function:

```
 mult :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
 mult 0 _ = 0
 mult x y = x * y

 main :: IO ()
 main = print . <test_function>
```

The results I got with `-prof -fprof-auto -O2`, `+RTS -p` were:

```
foldlp mult (/= 0) 1 $ replicate (10 ^ 7) 1
total time = 0.40 secs
total alloc = 480,049,336 bytes

foldlp mult (`seq` True) 1 $ replicate (10 ^ 7) 1
total time = 0.37 secs
total alloc = 480,049,336 bytes

foldl' mult 1 $ replicate (10 ^ 7) 1
total time = 0.37 secs
total alloc = 480,049,352 bytes

foldl mult 1 $ replicate (10 ^ 7) 1
total time = 0.74 secs
total alloc = 880,049,352 bytes

foldr mult 1 $ replicate (10 ^ 7) 1
total time = 0.87 secs
total alloc = 880,049,336 bytes
```

Which was very promising, as my custom function allows for flexible types of strictness, and also works on infinite lists

The first example will terminate as soon as it hits a `0`, as will `foldr`, but `foldr` is much slower.

It avoids issues such as thunks within tuples, seeing as `((1 + 2) + 3, (10 + 20) + 30)` is technically in WHNF, breaking `foldl'`.

You can re-obtain `foldl` with `flip foldl (const True)` and `foldl'` with `flip foldl (`seq`True)`. And the performance characteristics of the original restricted functions seem to be re-obtained by doing so.

So as a side note I think `foldlp` would be a worthwhile addition to `Foldable`.

But my actual question was why when I added `{-# INLINE foldlp #-}` the functions performance went down significantly, giving me:

```
foldlp mult (/= 0) 1 $ replicate (10 ^ 7) 1
total time = 0.67 secs
total alloc = 800,049,336 bytes
```

So my real question is why that is happening. I thought the downside of inlining was code bloat, not significant negative effects on runtime performance and increased memory usage.

Comment: Looks like forcing the inlining to happen earlier is causing some other rules to not fire properly...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the GHC docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.3/docs/html/users_guide/pragmas.html) the `INLINE` pragma prevents other compiler optimizations in order to still let rewrite rules take effect.

So my guess would be, that by using `INLINE` you remove some optimization, that GHC would have applied to make your code faster.

After some poking around in the core (use `-ddump-simpl` in compilation) I found the optimization, that GHC performs. For this I took a look at the core for `foldlp` with inlining and without inlining:

Inlined:

```
foldlp =
  \ (@ b_a10N)
    (@ a_a10O)
    (eta_B2 :: b_a10N -> a_a10O -> b_a10N)
    (eta1_B1 :: b_a10N -> Bool)
    (eta2_X3 :: b_a10N)
    (eta3_X5 :: [a_a10O]) ->
    letrec {
      go_s1Ao [Occ=LoopBreaker] :: b_a10N -> [a_a10O] -> b_a10N
      [LclId, Arity=2, Str=DmdType <L,U><S,1*U>]
      go_s1Ao =
        \ (b1_avT :: b_a10N) (ds_d1xQ :: [a_a10O]) ->
        -- Removed the actual definition of go for brevity,
        -- it's the same in both cases
          }; } in
    go_s1Ao eta2_X3 eta3_X5
```

Non-inlined:

```
foldlp =
  \ (@ b_a10N)
    (@ a_a10O)
    (f_avQ :: b_a10N -> a_a10O -> b_a10N)
    (p_avR :: b_a10N -> Bool) ->
    letrec {
      go_s1Am [Occ=LoopBreaker] :: b_a10N -> [a_a10O] -> b_a10N
      [LclId, Arity=2, Str=DmdType <L,U><S,1*U>]
      go_s1Am =
        \ (b1_avT :: b_a10N) (ds_d1xQ :: [a_a10O]) ->
        -- Removed the actual definition of go for brevity,
        -- it's the same in both cases
          }; } in
    go_s1Am
```

The relevant difference is in the very last line. The optimizer takes away the step of actually having to call `foldlp` to call `go` and just makes a function with two arguments out of foldlp that returns a function with two arguments. With inlining this optimization is not performed and the core looks exactly like the code you wrote.

I verified this by writing three variants of `foldlp`:

```
module Main where

foldlp :: (b -> a -> b) -> (b -> Bool) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldlp f p = go where
      go b [] = b
      go b (x : xs)
        | p b = go (f b x) xs
        | otherwise = b

{-# INLINE foldlpInline #-}
foldlpInline :: (b -> a -> b) -> (b -> Bool) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldlpInline f p = go where
      go b [] = b
      go b (x : xs)
        | p b = go (f b x) xs
        | otherwise = b


{-# INLINE foldlp' #-} -- So that the code is not optimized
foldlp' b [] = b
foldlp' b (x : xs)
        | (/= 0) b = foldlp' (mult b x) xs
        | otherwise = b

mult :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
mult 0 _ = 0
mult x y = x * y

--main = print $ foldlp mult (/= 0) 1 $ replicate (10 ^ 7) 1
--main = print $ foldlpInline mult (/= 0) 1 $ replicate (10 ^ 7) 1
main = print $ foldlp' 1 $ replicate (10 ^ 7) 1
```

The results are:

First case (normal non-inlined):

```
./test  0,42s user 0,01s system 96% cpu 0,446 total
```

Second case (inlined):

```
./test  0,83s user 0,02s system 98% cpu 0,862 total
```

Third case (what the compiler produces for non-inlined)

```
./test  0,42s user 0,01s system 99% cpu 0,432 total
```

Comment: Ok awesome thank you! In that case should I always leave foldlp not inlined? Or does it depend on the situation (across module boundaries for example). Is there a way to tell GHC to inline but try other optimizations first? `INLINABLE` perhaps?

Comment: From how I understand the docs, GHC automatically detects when it's advantageous to inline a function, and does so. So I would recommend not to use the ```INLINE``` pragma unless you have a specific reason.